# How do can I extract a spacific part of this string?

Tags: python-3.x, api, wrapper

Before I start I would like to say yes this is probably a noob question but I am kinda new to python

So when I request stats of a player for a specific game on this api I get a very long output of every stat like this.

```
{'first_join_7': True, 'bedwars_boxes': 34, 'Experience': 855892, 'games_played_bedwars_1': 3105, 'winstreak': 0, 'gold_resources_collected_bedwars': 46421, 'void_deaths_bedwars': 5226, 'eight_two_void_deaths_bedwars': 294, 'eight_two_deaths_bedwars': 496, 'eight_two__items_purchased_bedwars': 1520, 'deaths_bedwars': 8740, 'eight_two_games_played_bedwars': 191, 'resources_collected_bedwars': 357875, 'eight_two_items_purchased_bedwars': 1730, 'eight_two_resources_collected_bedwars': 20946, 'eight_two_gold_resources_collected_bedwars': 3346, 'coins': 505367, 'losses_bedwars': 1247, 'items_purchased_bedwars': 26210, 'games_played_bedwars': 1836, 'iron_resources_collected_bedwars': 304485, 'eight_two_iron_resources_collected_bedwars': 17306, 'eight_two_losses_bedwars': 162, '_items_purchased_bedwars': 22915, 'packages': ['v14_book', 'islandtopper_tnt', 'glyph_burn', 'glyph_lol', 'capture_book_0', 'glyph_hi', 'islandtopper_sheep', 'glyph_tnt', 'sprays_golem_riding', 'projectiletrail_lava', 'killeffect_heart_aura', 'projectiletrail_hearts', 'sprays_creeper', 'projectiletrail_angry_villager', 'victorydance_meteor_shower', 'projectiletrail_slime', 'islandtopper_treasure_chest', 'killeffect_firework', 'npcskin_holiday_bartender', 'sprays_leaping_potion', 'sprays_invisibility_potion', 'glyph_yes', 'projectiletrail_ender', 'sprays_hypixel_logo_default', 'killmessages_love', 'deathcry_enderman', 'killmessages_bbq', 'deathcry_dry_bones', 'projectiletrail_red_dust', 'islandtopper_heart', 'deathcry_pig', 'deathcry_fireball', 'islandtopper_gong', 'npcskin_bed_researcher', 'projectiletrail_white_smoke', 'glyph_thumbs_down', 'killmessages_western', 'sprays_enderman', 'glyph_diamond', 'glyph_iron', 'npcskin_zombie_pigman', 'victorydance_cold_snap', 'deathcry_ding', 'deathcry_grumble', 'sprays_thanks', 'projectiletrail_water', 'beddestroy_lighting_strike', 'npcskin_king_of_beds', 'deathcry_splash', 'sprays_sorry', 'npcskin_blaze', 'deathcry_bazinga', 'killeffect_campfire', 'npcskin_skeleton', 'npcskin_villager_zombie', 'islandtopper_smiley_face', 'killeffect_lighting_strike', 'killmessages_fire', 'glyph_gg', 'glyph_gold', 'glyph_bronze_shield', 'deathcry_bat', 'npcskin_astronaut', 'victorydance_yeehaw', 'npcskin_magic_vendor', 'sprays_dragon_slayer', 'killeffect_burning_shoes', 'projectiletrail_purple_dust', 'glyph_emerald', 'sprays_bye_bye', 'islandtopper_brick_house', 'npcskin_zombie', 'glyph_star', 'projectiletrail_green_star', 'deathcry_sad_puppy', 'glyph_smiley_face', 'victorydance_anvil_rain', 'killeffect_rekt', 'deathcry_monster_burp', 'islandtopper_bomb', 'islandtopper_whale', 'sprays_tnt_drop', 'killeffect_cookie_fountain', 'beddestroy_firework', 'killeffect_squid_missile', 'npcskin_witch', 'glyph_gold_shield', 'killeffect_head_rocket', 'deathcry_dinosaur', 'glyph_storm', 'glyph_sword', 'beddestroy_lava_explosion', 'glyph_thumbs_up', 'npcskin_bed_salesman', 'victorydance_special_fireworks', 'islandtopper_pumpkin', 'beddestroy_ghosts', 'deathcry_plop', 'islandtopper_sun_glasses', 'beddestroy_glyph', 'islandtopper_tree', 'islandtopper_candle', 'sprays_pumpkin', 'victorydance_dragon_rider', 'killmessages_glorious', 'sprays_grudge', 'glyph_spider', 'islandtopper_gargoyle', 'killeffect_black_mark', 'projectiletrail_random', 'islandtopper_thunder', 'islandtopper_clown', 'sprays_disco_pumpkin', 'npcskin_wither_skeleton', 'islandtopper_pot', 'deathcry_robot_mouse', 'projectiletrail_magic', 'glyph_silver_shield', 'islandtopper_rubix_cube', 'projectiletrail_black_smoke', 'projectiletrail_potion', 'beddestroy_tornado', 'deathcry_deflated_toy', 'glyph_no', 'glyph_daisy', 'killmessages_pirate', 'npcskin_creeper', 'sprays_gg_wp', 'killeffect_pi�ata', 'deathcry_gone', 'islandtopper_christmas_hat', 'favoritemap_jurassic', 'islandtopper_lantern', 'sprays_pig_peace', 'islandtopper_mark_of_the_paw', 'victorydance_toy_stick', 'islandtopper_reindeer', 'killeffect_snowplosion', 'glyph_elf', 'sprays_christmas_tree', 'victorydance_night_shift', 'glyph_candy_cane', 'projectiletrail_magic_wind', 'killeffect_candle', 'deathcry_miracle', 'glyph_gift', 'islandtopper_angel', 'beddestroy_thief', 'sprays_diamond', 'sprays_year_of_the_dog', 'glyph_earth', 'glyph_lantern', 'npcskin_wei', 'victorydance_fireworks', 'victorydance_guardians', 'victorydance_rainbow_dolly', 'killeffect_bunny_explosion', 'npcskin_ender_pulse', 'islandtopper_firework_rocket', 'killmessages_honourable', 'sprays_easter_creeper', 'islandtopper_bunny', 'glyph_angry_face', 'glyph_bed', 'islandtopper_flame', 'islandtopper_fish_bowl', 'deathcry_grumpy_villager', 'favoritemap_unturned', 'killeffect_tnt', 'killeffect_blood_explosion', 'killeffect_xp_orb', 'killeffect_smiley', 'killeffect_kill_counter_holo', '5_percent_multiplier_tournament'], 'quickjoin_uses_Invasion': 44, 'quickjoin_uses_total': 676, 'final_deaths_bedwars': 1234, 'four_three_beds_lost_bedwars': 364, 'beds_lost_bedwars': 1269, 'four_three_gold_resources_collected_bedwars': 15574, 'four_three_permanent _items_purchased_bedwars': 1048, 'four_three_iron_resources_collected_bedwars': 89893, 'four_three_losses_bedwars': 341, 'void_final_deaths_bedwars': 475, 'four_three_games_played_bedwars': 547, 'four_three__items_purchased_bedwars': 7482, 'permanent _items_purchased_bedwars': 3295, 'four_three_void_final_deaths_bedwars': 114, 'four_three_items_purchased_bedwars': 8530, 'four_three_final_deaths_bedwars': 342, 'four_three_resources_collected_bedwars': 107773, 'emerald_resources_collected_bedwars': 3428, 'eight_two_emerald_resources_collected_bedwars': 130, 'eight_two_permanent _items_purchased_bedwars': 210, 'eight_two_wins_bedwars': 15, 'wins_bedwars': 536, 'four_four__items_purchased_bedwars': 13439, 'void_kills_bedwars': 2600, 'four_four_permanent _items_purchased_bedwars': 1983, 'four_four_void_kills_bedwars': 1706, 'four_four_kills_bedwars': 3202, 'four_four_deaths_bedwars': 5434, 'four_four_gold_resources_collected_bedwars': 25676, 'four_four_entity_attack_deaths_bedwars': 1964, 'four_four_iron_resources_collected_bedwars': 189637, 'kills_bedwars': 4945, 'entity_attack_kills_bedwars': 2194, 'four_four_games_played_bedwars': 1070, 'four_four_wins_bedwars': 323, 'four_four_void_final_kills_bedwars': 311, 'entity_attack_deaths_bedwars': 3237, 'final_kills_bedwars': 1228, 'void_final_kills_bedwars': 536, 'four_four_resources_collected_bedwars': 219242, 'four_four_void_deaths_bedwars': 3304, 'four_four_items_purchased_bedwars': 15422, 'four_four_entity_attack_kills_bedwars': 1398, 'four_four_final_kills_bedwars': 732, 'four_four_emerald_resources_collected_bedwars': 1995, 'favorite_slots': 'Melee,null,Tools,null,Blocks,Potions,Utility,Ranged,null', 'eight_one_beds_lost_bedwars': 13, 'eight_one_final_deaths_bedwars': 16, 'eight_one_deaths_bedwars': 190, 'eight_one_void_deaths_bedwars': 106, 'eight_one_games_played_bedwars': 28, 'eight_one_entity_attack_deaths_bedwars': 79, 'eight_one_entity_attack_final_deaths_bedwars': 8, 'entity_attack_final_deaths_bedwars': 705, 'eight_one_losses_bedwars': 24, 'eight_one_iron_resources_collected_bedwars': 7649, 'eight_one__items_purchased_bedwars': 474, 'eight_one_items_purchased_bedwars': 528, 'eight_one_permanent _items_purchased_bedwars': 54, 'eight_one_void_kills_bedwars': 43, 'eight_one_kills_bedwars': 84, 'eight_one_resources_collected_bedwars': 9914, 'eight_one_gold_resources_collected_bedwars': 1825, 'eight_one_emerald_resources_collected_bedwars': 161, 'quickjoin_uses_random': 180, 'four_three_void_kills_bedwars': 736, 'four_three_entity_attack_kills_bedwars': 618, 'four_three_wins_bedwars': 196, 'four_three_emerald_resources_collected_bedwars': 1142, 'four_three_void_deaths_bedwars': 1522, 'four_three_entity_attack_deaths_bedwars': 1002, 'four_three_deaths_bedwars': 2620, 'four_three_beds_broken_bedwars': 205, 'four_three_kills_bedwars': 1403, 'beds_broken_bedwars': 431, 'selected_ultimate': 'SWORDSMAN', 'four_four_ultimate_winstreak': 1, 'four_four_ultimate_gold_resources_collected_bedwars': 11301, 'four_four_ultimate__items_purchased_bedwars': 5392, 'four_four_ultimate_resources_collected_bedwars': 98357, 'four_four_ultimate_beds_lost_bedwars': 443, 'four_four_ultimate_games_played_bedwars': 572, 'four_four_ultimate_items_purchased_bedwars': 6331, 'four_four_ultimate_void_final_deaths_bedwars': 190, 'four_four_ultimate_iron_resources_collected_bedwars': 85673, 'four_four_ultimate_final_deaths_bedwars': 430, 'four_four_ultimate_losses_bedwars': 425, 'four_four_ultimate_deaths_bedwars': 1529, 'four_four_ultimate_permanent _items_purchased_bedwars': 939, 'four_four_ultimate_emerald_resources_collected_bedwars': 564, 'four_four_ultimate_entity_attack_final_deaths_bedwars': 237, 'four_four_ultimate_void_deaths_bedwars': 992, 'four_four_ultimate_void_kills_bedwars': 514, 'four_four_ultimate_entity_attack_kills_bedwars': 447, 'four_four_ultimate_wins_bedwars': 122, 'four_four_ultimate_entity_attack_deaths_bedwars': 534, 'four_four_ultimate_kills_bedwars': 962, 'four_four_ultimate_diamond_resources_collected_bedwars': 819, 'eight_two_winstreak': 0, 'eight_two_final_deaths_bedwars': 167, 'eight_two_entity_attack_final_deaths_bedwars': 94, 'eight_two_beds_lost_bedwars': 156, 'diamond_resources_collected_bedwars': 3541, 'eight_two_diamond_resources_collected_bedwars': 164, 'eight_two_kills_bedwars': 256, 'eight_two_entity_attack_kills_bedwars': 137, 'eight_two_void_kills_bedwars': 115, 'eight_two_entity_attack_deaths_bedwars': 192, 'eight_two_ultimate_winstreak': 0, 'eight_two_ultimate_iron_resources_collected_bedwars': 4506, 'eight_two_ultimate_void_final_deaths_bedwars': 9, 'eight_two_ultimate_final_deaths_bedwars': 28, 'eight_two_ultimate__items_purchased_bedwars': 290, 'eight_two_ultimate_losses_bedwars': 28, 'eight_two_ultimate_gold_resources_collected_bedwars': 861, 'eight_two_ultimate_resources_collected_bedwars': 5520, 'eight_two_ultimate_beds_lost_bedwars': 29, 'eight_two_ultimate_games_played_bedwars': 36, 'eight_two_ultimate_items_purchased_bedwars': 337, 'eight_two_ultimate_entity_attack_final_deaths_bedwars': 19, 'eight_two_ultimate_deaths_bedwars': 70, 'eight_two_ultimate_entity_attack_deaths_bedwars': 21, 'eight_two_ultimate_emerald_resources_collected_bedwars': 44, 'eight_two_ultimate_permanent _items_purchased_bedwars': 47, 'eight_two_ultimate_void_deaths_bedwars': 49, 'eight_two_ultimate_void_kills_bedwars': 13, 'eight_two_ultimate_kills_bedwars': 33, 'eight_two_ultimate_beds_broken_bedwars': 17, 'eight_two_ultimate_wins_bedwars': 7, 'eight_two_ultimate_entity_attack_final_kills_bedwars': 14, 'eight_two_ultimate_diamond_resources_collected_bedwars': 109, 'eight_two_ultimate_final_kills_bedwars': 22, 'eight_two_ultimate_void_final_kills_bedwars': 8, 'four_four_winstreak': 0, 'four_four_final_deaths_bedwars': 709, 'four_four_beds_lost_bedwars': 736, 'four_four_losses_bedwars': 720, 'four_four_entity_attack_final_deaths_bedwars': 396, 'entity_attack_final_kills_bedwars': 658, 'four_four_entity_attack_final_kills_bedwars': 400, 'four_four_diamond_resources_collected_bedwars': 1934, 'four_four_void_final_deaths_bedwars': 284, 'four_four_beds_broken_bedwars': 185, 'four_four_ultimate_final_kills_bedwars': 295, 'four_four_ultimate_entity_attack_final_kills_bedwars': 141, 'four_four_ultimate_void_final_kills_bedwars': 154, 'four_three_winstreak': 0, 'four_three_entity_attack_final_deaths_bedwars': 207, 'fall_deaths_bedwars': 219, 'four_three_fall_deaths_bedwars': 75, 'quickjoin_uses_Amazon': 1, 'eight_two_void_final_deaths_bedwars': 70, 'four_four_ultimate_beds_broken_bedwars': 96, 'shop_sort': 'rarity_descending', 'Bedwars_openedChests': 376, 'Bedwars_openedCommons': 209, 'Bedwars_openedRares': 127, 'chest_history_new': ['victorydance_yeehaw', 'killmessages_fire', 'sprays_disco_pumpkin', 'islandtopper_rubix_cube', 'glyph_star'], 'activeGlyph': 'random_cosmetic', 'eight_one_winstreak': 0, 'eight_one_diamond_resources_collected_bedwars': 279, 'eight_one_entity_attack_kills_bedwars': 41, 'eight_one_void_final_deaths_bedwars': 7, 'activeSprays': 'random_cosmetic', 'quickjoin_uses_Waterfall': 2, 'eight_two_beds_broken_bedwars': 38, 'eight_two_entity_attack_final_kills_bedwars': 36, 'eight_two_final_kills_bedwars': 68, 'eight_two_ultimate_entity_attack_kills_bedwars': 20, 'eight_two_entity_explosion_kills_bedwars': 2, 'entity_explosion_kills_bedwars': 14, 'four_four_ultimate_fire_tick_final_deaths_bedwars': 1, 'favourites_2': 'wool,stone_sword,chainmail_boots,blast-proof_glass,bow,speed_ii_potion_(45_seconds),tnt,oak_wood_planks,iron_sword,iron_boots,shears,arrow,invisibility_potion_(30_seconds),magic_milk,end_stone,diamond_sword,diamond_boots,wooden_axe,wooden_pickaxe,jump_v_potion_(45_seconds),fireball', 'understands_streaks': True, 'understands_resource_bank': True, 'castle_beds_lost_bedwars': 233, 'castle_permanent _items_purchased_bedwars': 343, 'castle_deaths_bedwars': 474, 'castle__items_purchased_bedwars': 2603, 'castle_games_played_bedwars': 86, 'castle_items_purchased_bedwars': 2946, 'castle_gold_resources_collected_bedwars': 5699, 'castle_resources_collected_bedwars': 38923, 'castle_losses_bedwars': 65, 'castle_void_deaths_bedwars': 325, 'castle_iron_resources_collected_bedwars': 32481, 'castle_winstreak': 1, 'castle_entity_attack_final_deaths_bedwars': 31, 'castle_wins_bedwars': 59, 'castle_final_deaths_bedwars': 59, 'castle_diamond_resources_collected_bedwars': 506, 'castle_entity_attack_deaths_bedwars': 109, 'castle_emerald_resources_collected_bedwars': 237, 'castle_entity_attack_kills_bedwars': 137, 'castle_kills_bedwars': 270, 'castle_fall_deaths_bedwars': 31, 'castle_void_kills_bedwars': 117, 'castle_void_final_deaths_bedwars': 11, 'castle_void_final_kills_bedwars': 10, 'castle_final_kills_bedwars': 33, 'castle_fall_kills_bedwars': 11, 'castle_fire_tick_deaths_bedwars': 1, 'four_four_projectile_kills_bedwars': 1, 'projectile_kills_bedwars': 1, 'four_four_entity_explosion_kills_bedwars': 10, 'fall_kills_bedwars': 134, 'four_four_fall_kills_bedwars': 86, 'four_three_diamond_resources_collected_bedwars': 1164, 'eight_two_void_final_kills_bedwars': 29, 'entity_explosion_deaths_bedwars': 18, 'eight_two_entity_explosion_deaths_bedwars': 3, 'quickjoin_uses_Jurassic': 223, 'quickjoin_uses_Stonekeep': 5, 'four_four_projectile_deaths_bedwars': 22, 'projectile_deaths_bedwars': 38, 'four_four_rush_winstreak': 6, 'four_four_rush_kills_bedwars': 756, 'four_four_rush_losses_bedwars': 325, 'four_four_rush_items_purchased_bedwars': 4367, 'four_four_rush_games_played_bedwars': 403, 'four_four_rush_entity_attack_final_deaths_bedwars': 159, 'four_four_rush_emerald_resources_collected_bedwars': 2765, 'four_four_rush_beds_lost_bedwars': 321, 'four_four_rush_gold_resources_collected_bedwars': 8423, 'four_four_rush_resources_collected_bedwars': 77879, 'four_four_rush_final_deaths_bedwars': 319, 'four_four_rush_entity_attack_kills_bedwars': 370, 'four_four_rush__items_purchased_bedwars': 3575, 'four_four_rush_permanent _items_purchased_bedwars': 792, 'four_four_rush_iron_resources_collected_bedwars': 66085, 'four_four_rush_deaths_bedwars': 1374, 'four_four_rush_entity_attack_deaths_bedwars': 482, 'four_four_rush_void_deaths_bedwars': 861, 'four_four_rush_beds_broken_bedwars': 51, 'four_four_rush_void_final_deaths_bedwars': 142, 'four_four_rush_void_kills_bedwars': 372, 'four_four_fall_deaths_bedwars': 135, 'four_four_rush_entity_attack_final_kills_bedwars': 101, 'four_four_rush_void_final_kills_bedwars': 91, 'four_four_rush_final_kills_bedwars': 199, 'four_four_rush_diamond_resources_collected_bedwars': 606, 'four_four_rush_wins_bedwars': 74, 'eight_two_rush_winstreak': 0, 'eight_two_rush_items_purchased_bedwars': 83, 'eight_two_rush_losses_bedwars': 16, 'eight_two_rush_void_final_deaths_bedwars': 5, 'eight_two_rush__items_purchased_bedwars': 72, 'eight_two_rush_resources_collected_bedwars': 1137, 'eight_two_rush_emerald_resources_collected_bedwars': 56, 'eight_two_rush_gold_resources_collected_bedwars': 179, 'eight_two_rush_games_played_bedwars': 16, 'eight_two_rush_beds_lost_bedwars': 16, 'eight_two_rush_final_deaths_bedwars': 16, 'eight_two_rush_iron_resources_collected_bedwars': 888, 'eight_two_rush_kills_bedwars': 41, 'eight_two_rush_deaths_bedwars': 44, 'eight_two_rush_void_kills_bedwars': 17, 'eight_two_rush_void_deaths_bedwars': 22, 'eight_two_rush_entity_attack_kills_bedwars': 23, 'fall_final_deaths_bedwars': 38, 'four_four_fall_final_deaths_bedwars': 19, 'four_three_fall_final_deaths_bedwars': 16, 'four_four_rush_fall_final_deaths_bedwars': 15, 'four_four_rush_fall_deaths_bedwars': 29, 'four_four_rush_entity_explosion_kills_bedwars': 2, 'four_three_void_final_kills_bedwars': 193, 'four_three_final_kills_bedwars': 419, 'eight_one_ultimate_winstreak': 0, 'eight_one_ultimate_losses_bedwars': 1, 'eight_one_ultimate_games_played_bedwars': 1, 'eight_one_ultimate_items_purchased_bedwars': 8, 'eight_one_ultimate_permanent _items_purchased_bedwars': 2, 'eight_one_ultimate_entity_attack_final_deaths_bedwars': 1, 'eight_one_ultimate_final_deaths_bedwars': 1, 'eight_one_ultimate_iron_resources_collected_bedwars': 125, 'eight_one_ultimate__items_purchased_bedwars': 6, 'eight_one_ultimate_resources_collected_bedwars': 153, 'eight_one_ultimate_gold_resources_collected_bedwars': 28, 'eight_one_ultimate_beds_lost_bedwars': 1, 'quickjoin_uses_Ashore': 52, 'activeIslandTopper': 'random_cosmetic', 'activeProjectileTrail': 'random_cosmetic', 'Bedwars_openedLegendaries': 10, 'Bedwars_openedEpics': 32, 'activeVictoryDance': 'victorydance_dragon_rider', 'activeNPCSkin': 'random_cosmetic', 'activeKillEffect': 'killeffect_kill_counter_holo', 'activeDeathCry': 'random_cosmetic', 'activeBedDestroy': 'random_cosmetic', 'activeKillMessages': 'killmessages_glorious', 'eight_one_beds_broken_bedwars': 3, 'four_three_fire_kills_bedwars': 1, 'fire_kills_bedwars': 1, 'four_four_ultimate_entity_explosion_final_deaths_bedwars': 2, 'castle_fall_final_deaths_bedwars': 14, 'quickjoin_uses_Dragonstar': 3, 'quickjoin_uses_Steampunk': 1, 'quickjoin_uses_Chained': 7, 'quickjoin_uses_Treenan': 6, 'quickjoin_uses_Crypt': 2, 'four_three_fall_kills_bedwars': 46, 'four_three_entity_attack_final_kills_bedwars': 216, 'four_three_entity_explosion_deaths_bedwars': 7, 'eight_two_fall_deaths_bedwars': 6, 'four_four_entity_explosion_final_deaths_bedwars': 6, 'entity_explosion_final_deaths_bedwars': 11, 'quickjoin_uses_Archway': 7, 'four_four_projectile_final_deaths_bedwars': 3, 'projectile_final_deaths_bedwars': 4, 'quickjoin_uses_Lectus': 8, 'quickjoin_uses_Sandcastle': 5, 'quickjoin_uses_Lighthouse': 3, 'entity_explosion_final_kills_bedwars': 4, 'four_four_entity_explosion_final_kills_bedwars': 3, 'four_four_entity_explosion_deaths_bedwars': 8, 'eight_one_entity_attack_final_kills_bedwars': 6, 'eight_one_final_kills_bedwars': 9, 'eight_one_void_final_kills_bedwars': 3, 'eight_one_wins_bedwars': 2, 'eight_two_fall_final_deaths_bedwars': 2, 'quickjoin_uses_Playground': 1, 'eight_two_rush_entity_attack_deaths_bedwars': 21, 'eight_two_rush_entity_attack_final_deaths_bedwars': 10, 'four_four_rush_projectile_final_deaths_bedwars': 1, 'four_four_rush_fall_kills_bedwars': 12, 'eight_two_rush_beds_broken_bedwars': 2, 'eight_two_rush_diamond_resources_collected_bedwars': 14, 'eight_two_rush_permanent _items_purchased_bedwars': 11, 'four_four_rush_fall_final_kills_bedwars': 7, 'eight_two_entity_explosion_final_kills_bedwars': 1, 'four_four_rush_entity_explosion_deaths_bedwars': 2, 'quickjoin_uses_Swashbuckle': 13, 'quickjoin_uses_Eastwood': 14, 'four_four_ultimate_entity_explosion_deaths_bedwars': 1, 'eight_two_fall_final_kills_bedwars': 2, 'fall_final_kills_bedwars': 30, 'eight_one_fall_deaths_bedwars': 3, 'eight_one_fall_final_deaths_bedwars': 1, 'eight_one_projectile_deaths_bedwars': 2, 'eight_two_entity_explosion_final_deaths_bedwars': 1, 'four_four_fall_final_kills_bedwars': 18, 'bedwars_halloween_boxes': 25, 'quickjoin_uses_Temple': 7, 'free_event_key_bedwars_halloween_boxes_2018': True, 'spooky_open_ach': 16, 'quickjoin_uses_Boletum': 8, 'fire_tick_kills_bedwars': 1, 'four_four_fire_tick_kills_bedwars': 1, 'quickjoin_uses_Aquarium': 7, 'four_three_projectile_final_deaths_bedwars': 1, 'eight_two_fall_kills_bedwars': 2, 'four_three_entity_explosion_final_deaths_bedwars': 4, 'four_four_rush_entity_explosion_final_deaths_bedwars': 2, 'lastTourneyAd': 1543161524267, 'four_four_ultimate_entity_explosion_kills_bedwars': 1, 'tourney_bedwars4s_0_final_deaths_bedwars': 33, 'tourney_bedwars4s_0_void_kills_bedwars': 69, 'tourney_bedwars4s_0__items_purchased_bedwars': 462, 'tourney_bedwars4s_0_items_purchased_bedwars': 557, 'tourney_bedwars4s_0_beds_lost_bedwars': 35, 'tourney_bedwars4s_0_losses_bedwars': 35, 'tourney_bedwars4s_0_void_deaths_bedwars': 137, 'tourney_bedwars4s_0_entity_attack_kills_bedwars': 70, 'tourney_bedwars4s_0_resources_collected_bedwars': 9328, 'tourney_bedwars4s_0_iron_resources_collected_bedwars': 8139, 'tourney_bedwars4s_0_deaths_bedwars': 230, 'tourney_bedwars4s_0_games_played_bedwars': 48, 'tourney_bedwars4s_0_permanent _items_purchased_bedwars': 95, 'tourney_bedwars4s_0_entity_attack_final_deaths_bedwars': 22, 'tourney_bedwars4s_0_gold_resources_collected_bedwars': 1067, 'tourney_bedwars4s_0_kills_bedwars': 144, 'tourney_bedwars4s_0_entity_attack_deaths_bedwars': 87, 'tourney_bedwars4s_0_winstreak': 11, 'tourney_bedwars4s_0_beds_broken_bedwars': 5, 'tourney_bedwars4s_0_final_kills_bedwars': 31, 'tourney_bedwars4s_0_wins_bedwars': 11, 'tourney_bedwars4s_0_entity_attack_final_kills_bedwars': 12, 'tourney_bedwars4s_0_void_final_kills_bedwars': 17, 'tourney_bedwars4s_0_void_final_deaths_bedwars': 10, 'tourney_bedwars4s_0_emerald_resources_collected_bedwars': 78, 'tourney_bedwars4s_0_fall_deaths_bedwars': 6, 'tourney_bedwars4s_0_fall_kills_bedwars': 5, 'tourney_bedwars4s_0_fall_final_kills_bedwars': 2, 'tourney_bedwars4s_0_diamond_resources_collected_bedwars': 44, 'tourney_bedwars4s_0_fall_final_deaths_bedwars': 1, 'tourney_bedwars4s_0_winstreak2': 0, 'four_four_ultimate_projectile_deaths_bedwars': 2, 'eight_two_projectile_deaths_bedwars': 1, 'bedwars_christmas_boxes': 0, 'free_event_key_bedwars_christmas_boxes_2018': True, 'four_three_projectile_deaths_bedwars': 13, 'voted_fortress': True, 'quickjoin_uses_Wrapped Up': 9, 'quickjoin_uses_Gingerbread': 4, 'lastHytaleAd': 1544901203444, 'voted_snowman': True, 'shop_sort_enable_owned_first': False, 'bedwars_lunar_boxes': 0, 'free_event_key_bedwars_lunar_boxes_2019': True, 'four_four_lucky_winstreak': 0, 'four_four_lucky_void_deaths_bedwars': 258, 'four_four_lucky_permanent _items_purchased_bedwars': 172, 'four_four_lucky_items_purchased_bedwars': 1470, 'four_four_lucky_final_deaths_bedwars': 61, 'four_four_lucky_losses_bedwars': 64, 'four_four_lucky_games_played_bedwars': 86, 'four_four_lucky__items_purchased_bedwars': 1298, 'four_four_lucky_entity_attack_final_deaths_bedwars': 23, 'four_four_lucky_resources_collected_bedwars': 23658, 'four_four_lucky_deaths_bedwars': 406, 'four_four_lucky_iron_resources_collected_bedwars': 20440, 'four_four_lucky_beds_lost_bedwars': 62, 'four_four_lucky_gold_resources_collected_bedwars': 2853, 'four_four_lucky_kills_bedwars': 225, 'four_four_lucky_void_kills_bedwars': 136, 'four_four_lucky_void_final_deaths_bedwars': 33, 'four_four_lucky_diamond_resources_collected_bedwars': 176, 'four_four_lucky_entity_attack_kills_bedwars': 78, 'four_four_lucky_beds_broken_bedwars': 53, 'four_four_lucky_final_kills_bedwars': 93, 'four_four_lucky_void_final_kills_bedwars': 48, 'four_four_lucky_magic_deaths_bedwars': 1, 'four_four_lucky_fall_deaths_bedwars': 17, 'four_four_lucky_wins_bedwars': 20, 'four_four_lucky_entity_attack_deaths_bedwars': 111, 'four_four_lucky_projectile_deaths_bedwars': 4, 'four_four_lucky_entity_attack_final_kills_bedwars': 37, 'four_four_lucky_fire_tick_deaths_bedwars': 11, 'four_four_lucky_emerald_resources_collected_bedwars': 189, 'four_four_lucky_fire_tick_final_kills_bedwars': 3, 'four_four_lucky_fall_final_kills_bedwars': 4, 'four_four_lucky_fire_kills_bedwars': 1, 'four_four_lucky_fall_kills_bedwars': 8, 'four_four_lucky_entity_explosion_deaths_bedwars': 3, 'four_four_lucky_fall_final_deaths_bedwars': 4, 'four_four_lucky_fire_tick_kills_bedwars': 2, 'four_four_lucky_fire_deaths_bedwars': 1, 'four_four_lucky_entity_explosion_final_kills_bedwars': 1, 'eight_two_lucky_winstreak': 0, 'eight_two_lucky_deaths_bedwars': 7, 'eight_two_lucky_void_kills_bedwars': 3, 'eight_two_lucky_beds_broken_bedwars': 2, 'eight_two_lucky_fall_deaths_bedwars': 1, 'eight_two_lucky_losses_bedwars': 3, 'eight_two_lucky_permanent _items_purchased_bedwars': 8, 'eight_two_lucky_iron_resources_collected_bedwars': 364, 'eight_two_lucky_void_deaths_bedwars': 3, 'eight_two_lucky_kills_bedwars': 3, 'eight_two_lucky_gold_resources_collected_bedwars': 70, 'eight_two_lucky_resources_collected_bedwars': 437, 'eight_two_lucky_final_kills_bedwars': 4, 'eight_two_lucky_items_purchased_bedwars': 46, 'eight_two_lucky_void_final_kills_bedwars': 2, 'eight_two_lucky_beds_lost_bedwars': 2, 'eight_two_lucky_games_played_bedwars': 4, 'eight_two_lucky_final_deaths_bedwars': 3, 'eight_two_lucky__items_purchased_bedwars': 38, 'eight_two_lucky_void_final_deaths_bedwars': 2, 'eight_two_lucky_entity_attack_final_deaths_bedwars': 1, 'eight_two_lucky_entity_attack_final_kills_bedwars': 2, 'eight_two_lucky_diamond_resources_collected_bedwars': 3, 'eight_two_lucky_fire_tick_deaths_bedwars': 2, 'eight_two_lucky_entity_attack_deaths_bedwars': 1, 'four_four_lucky_fire_tick_final_deaths_bedwars': 1, 'castle_fall_final_kills_bedwars': 3, 'castle_entity_attack_final_kills_bedwars': 20, 'voted_fortress2': True, 'castle_projectile_deaths_bedwars': 4, 'castle_beds_broken_bedwars': 3, 'castle_entity_explosion_kills_bedwars': 3, 'castle_entity_explosion_final_deaths_bedwars': 3, 'castle_fire_tick_kills_bedwars': 2, 'castle_entity_explosion_deaths_bedwars': 4, 'bedwars_easter_boxes': 1, 'free_event_key_bedwars_easter_boxes_2019': True, 'eight_two_rush_final_kills_bedwars': 4, 'eight_two_rush_void_final_kills_bedwars': 4, 'eight_two_rush_fall_kills_bedwars': 1, 'eight_two_rush_fall_deaths_bedwars': 1, 'eight_two_rush_projectile_final_deaths_bedwars': 1, 'four_three_fall_final_kills_bedwars': 10, 'quickjoin_uses_Lotus': 2, 'quickjoin_uses_Hollow': 1, 'quickjoin_uses_Pernicious': 1, 'four_four_voidless_winstreak': 2, 'four_four_voidless__items_purchased_bedwars': 146, 'four_four_voidless_beds_lost_bedwars': 14, 'four_four_voidless_deaths_bedwars': 27, 'four_four_voidless_entity_attack_final_deaths_bedwars': 8, 'four_four_voidless_final_deaths_bedwars': 10, 'four_four_voidless_games_played_bedwars': 16, 'four_four_voidless_gold_resources_collected_bedwars': 223, 'four_four_voidless_iron_resources_collected_bedwars': 1672, 'four_four_voidless_items_purchased_bedwars': 163, 'four_four_voidless_losses_bedwars': 11, 'four_four_voidless_resources_collected_bedwars': 1919, 'four_four_voidless_void_deaths_bedwars': 6, 'four_four_voidless_entity_attack_deaths_bedwars': 18, 'four_four_voidless_entity_attack_kills_bedwars': 16, 'four_four_voidless_kills_bedwars': 19, 'four_four_voidless_permanent _items_purchased_bedwars': 17, 'four_four_voidless_void_final_deaths_bedwars': 2, 'four_four_voidless_fall_kills_bedwars': 3, 'quickjoin_uses_Dreamgrove': 15, 'quickjoin_uses_Carapace': 8, 'quickjoin_uses_Unturned': 32, 'quickjoin_uses_Obelisk': 5, 'four_three_entity_explosion_kills_bedwars': 2, 'four_four_armed_winstreak': 0, 'four_four_armed__items_purchased_bedwars': 7, 'four_four_armed_deaths_bedwars': 5, 'four_four_armed_entity_attack_kills_bedwars': 2, 'four_four_armed_games_played_bedwars': 1, 'four_four_armed_gold_resources_collected_bedwars': 4, 'four_four_armed_iron_resources_collected_bedwars': 46, 'four_four_armed_items_purchased_bedwars': 7, 'four_four_armed_kills_bedwars': 3, 'four_four_armed_losses_bedwars': 1, 'four_four_armed_projectile_deaths_bedwars': 3, 'four_four_armed_projectile_kills_bedwars': 1, 'four_four_armed_resources_collected_bedwars': 50, 'four_four_armed_void_deaths_bedwars': 2, 'fire_tick_deaths_bedwars': 2, 'four_three_fire_tick_deaths_bedwars': 1, 'free_event_key_bedwars_halloween_boxes_2019': True, 'fire_tick_final_deaths_bedwars': 1, 'four_four_fire_tick_final_deaths_bedwars': 1, 'four_four_voidless_emerald_resources_collected_bedwars': 16, 'four_four_voidless_entity_attack_final_kills_bedwars': 7, 'four_four_voidless_fall_deaths_bedwars': 3, 'four_four_voidless_final_kills_bedwars': 10, 'four_four_voidless_wins_bedwars': 5, 'four_four_voidless_diamond_resources_collected_bedwars': 8, 'four_four_voidless_beds_broken_bedwars': 3, 'four_four_voidless_fall_final_kills_bedwars': 3, 'four_four_fire_tick_deaths_bedwars'
```

now as you can see it is very, very long! but let's say I only want the 'winstreak': 0, ' to be displayed how can I only get that part to print?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The api is returning a dictionary.  Suppose what you are printing above is in a variable 'mydict'....then just print 'mydict[winstreak]' instead.